# Maven Wrapper and generated

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to add maven wrapper to my code

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

But when executing it, it gives me an error with the classes that my plugin generates "maven-processor-plugin"

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source output directory -->
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Execute

```
 ./mvnw clean install
```

Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project elser30: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.xxx.domain.PeticionUsuario_
[ERROR] Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.xxx.domain.Puesto_
[ERROR] Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.xxx.domain.DatoAuxiliar_
```

Comment: You not configure the outputdirectory to put generated code into `src/main/*` because generated code should be put into `target/*` which I bet that the default of the plugin is already that...also the [docs telling me](https://bsorrentino.github.io/maven-annotation-plugin/usage.html) that your setup and defining the `outputDirectory` is wrong...

Comment: Is there any solution known for this problem?